# AWS Presigned URL works with Python's Requests library but fails with cURL

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, python-requests, pre-signed-url

Recently I started using AWS pre-signed URLs to upload files to S3. The generated pre-signed URLs are working perfectly when using Python's `Requests` library as follows:

**Generating the pre-signed url:**

```py
def create_presigned_post(bucket_name, object_name,
                          fields=None, conditions=None, expiration=3600):
    """Generate a presigned URL S3 POST request to upload a file

    :param bucket_name: string
    :param object_name: string
    :param fields: Dictionary of prefilled form fields
    :param conditions: List of conditions to include in the policy
    :param expiration: Time in seconds for the presigned URL to remain valid
    :return: Dictionary with the following keys:
        url: URL to post to
        fields: Dictionary of form fields and values to submit with the POST
    :return: None if error.
    """

    # Generate a presigned S3 POST URL
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    try:
        response = s3_client.generate_presigned_post(bucket_name,
                                                     object_name,
                                                     Fields=fields,
                                                     Conditions=conditions,
                                                     ExpiresIn=expiration)
    except ClientError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return None

    # The response contains the presigned URL and required fields
    return response
```

**Running the request to get the presigned url**

```py
# Getting a presigned_url to upload the file into S3 Bucket.
        headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'request': 'upload_url', 'target': FILENAME, 'x-api-key': API_KEY}

        r_upload = requests.post(url = API_ENDPOINT, headers = headers)

        url = json.loads(json.loads(r_upload.text)['body'])['url']
        fields_ = json.loads(json.loads(r_upload.text)['body'])['fields']
        fields = {
                "x-amz-algorithm": fields_["x-amz-algorithm"],
                "key": fields_["key"],
                "policy": fields_["policy"],
                "x-amz-signature": fields_["x-amz-signature"],
                "x-amz-date": fields_["x-amz-date"],
                "x-amz-credential": fields_["x-amz-credential"],
                "x-amz-security-token":  fields_["x-amz-security-token"]
        }

        fileobj = open(FILENAME, 'rb')
        http_response = requests.post(url, data=fields,files={'file': (FILENAME, fileobj)})
```

**Valid Response**

```
 "{\"url\": \"https://****.s3.amazonaws.com/\", 
   \"fields\": 
        {\"key\": \"******\", \"x-amz-algorithm\": \"*******\", \"x-amz-credential\": \"*******\", \"x-amz-date\": \"*********\", \"x-amz-security-token\": \"********", \"policy\": \"**********\", \"x-amz-signature\": \"*******\"}}
```

And as you can see I'm providing no `AWSAccessKey` or any credentials when uploading the file using the generated pre-signed URL and this is so logical, as the pre-signed URL is created to be given for external users who have to provide no credentials when using such URL.

However and when trying to run the same call made by Python's `Requests` library, using cURL, the request is failing with the error:

```sh
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><Error>
```

To get the exact request call made by `requests.post`, I'm running:

```py
req = http_response.request
command = "curl -X {method} -H {headers} -d '{data}' '{uri}'"
method = "PUT"
uri = req.url
data = req.body
headers = ['"{0}: {1}"'.format(k, v) for k, v in req.headers.items()]
headers = " -H ".join(headers)
print(command.format(method=method, headers=headers, data=data, uri=uri))
```

Which returns:

```sh
curl -v -X PUT -H "Connection: keep-alive" --upload-file xxxx.zip -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" -H "Accept: */*" -H "User-Agent: python-requests/2.18.4" -H "Content-Length: xxxx" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=8a9864bdxxxxx00100ba04cc055a" -d '--8a9864bd377041xxxxx04cc055a
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="x-amz-algorithm"
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256

--8a9864bd377041e0b00100ba04cc055a
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="key"
xxxxx.zip

--8a9864bd377041e0b00100ba04cc055a
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="x-amz-signature"
*****

--8a9864bd377041e0b00100ba04cc055a
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="x-amz-security-token"
*****

--8a9864bd377041e0b00100ba04cc055a
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="x-amz-date"
*****

--8a9864bd377041e0b00100ba04cc055a
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="policy"
*****

--8a9864bd377041e0b00100ba04cc055a
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="x-amz-credential"
xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxx/s3/aws4_request

' 'https://xxxxx.s3.amazonaws.com/'
```

Then reformulate it:

```
$ curl -v -T file "https://****.s3.amazonaws.com/?key=************&x-amz-algorithm=***************&x-amz-credential=*************&x-amz-security-token=************&policy=**********&x-amz-signature=****************
```

After researching, I found nothing similar to this issue, but:
https://aws.amazon.com/es/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-access-denied-error/

This still seem not logical to me because I'm not supposed to enter any credentials when using a pre-signed URL.

I don't know if I'm missing something of the complete request made by Python's `Requests` library.

Any ideas, please!

Kind regards,

Rshad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This simple curl command should work:

With a usual presigned url, it would be as follows:

```sh
curl -v \
-F key=<filename> \
-F x-amz-algorithm=*** \
-F x-amz-credential=*** \
-F x-amz-date=*** \
-F x-amz-security-token=*** \
-F policy=*** \
-F x-amz-signature=*** \
-F file=@<filename> \
'https://<bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/'
```

The -F field allows you to specify the additional POST data that should be uploaded to S3 (i.e. from the fields data returned w/ the pre-signed URLs.

Kind regards,

Comment: Hi Ashaman! Please check the description again, I adapted it with more details

Comment: Hmm, maybe set the Content-Type header and also enclose the URL in single-quotes.  When you are generating the pre-signed URL, what content-type are you expecting?

Comment: @Rshad any progress on this?

Comment: Hi @Ashman ! Sorry for the delay.  I already tried setting the content-type in the header and enclosing the URL in single-quotes, but nothing changed. As a result, I'm waiting for "application/json" content-type.

Comment: @Rshad can you post the code you are using to generate the URL, I will try it locally.

Comment: @Rshad, Where did you add it?  The first code snippet in your question appears to be invoking some custom API that generates the presigned URL that you are later using.  It is that custom code that is using the AWS API to generate the presigned URL that I want to see.  Your code is python but I don't see where you are using the python AWS SDK to create the presigned URL so I'm assuming you have another piece of code somewhere that is doing it.

Comment: @Ashman! Ah okay, you meant the code running in Lambda, I'm using the function `create_presigned_post`. check it in the question.

Comment: @Rshad Thanks, I think the problem is that with curl we are not submitting the post data with it.  My understanding of the documentation is that the data returned in fields has to be included in the subsequent POST request.  I've updated my answer to reflect this.  Give it a try!

Comment: Hi @Ashaman, I understand, the fields included in the pre-signed url are used to upload the file then. you can check that I already do that with python. regarding curl I tested both ways, to pass the fields as data with `--data` or to pass them as parameters <bucket.s3.amazon.com.../?fields> and both cases still failing!

Comment: @Rshad, can you provide the exact curl command you are using with the --data option? Are you passing in the data as JSON?

Comment: Thanks a lot man, the last solution you proposed using '-F' works perfectly. Really appreciated. I hope this answer could be marked as the correct one because it is.

Comment: @Rshad Great, let me modify my answer to only contain that curl command and then you can mark it as answered.  Glad it worked!

Comment: Hi @Ashaman! I've just marked your answer as the correct one and updated it with the complete pre-signed URL attributes I had in my case. Thanks again!

Comment: Any luck with this. I'm having the same problem with the python requests library. Any solution with python requests?

Comment: Hi @fahad, In my main question I indicated that I had no problem with Python and I posted the corresponding code to do so, you can check it. The problem was when running the `curl` command from the command line. I hope it helps.